# How can I audit commands executed by a user without installing acct

Tags: command-line, history

I want to audit commands executed for two accounts on my ubuntu desktop about a year ago. I know of acct [sudo apt-get install acct] where I can run lastcomm, dump-acct, dump-utmp but I want a different method where I don't need to install anything (acct..etc). If possible, can I know the location where acct picks information/data from.

Comment: Are you just looking for the `/home/username/.bash_history` file?

Comment: You are trying to see commands that other accounts ran about a year ago?  You probably want to look in the Bash History file like @terdon said.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `acct` to audit events that occurred before it was configured or installed, as it is a background service that collects that information. That said, here are some alternatives:

## .bash_history (or other shells' history)

is a file in a user's home directory (`/home/username/.bash_history`) in which the Bourne Again Shell (the default in Ubuntu) stores its command history (which you access when you press the up arrow to repeat a previous command, among other things).

The user may use a different shell. You can check what shell they use by running the command `getent passwd username`. It is located here:

```
$ getent passwd username
username:x:1000:1000:User Name,,,:/home/username:/bin/bash
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^
```

Other shells' history files are:

```
bash    .bash_history
csh     .history
zsh     Hard to say, could be .histfile, .zhistory, or .zsh_history, or something else entirely.
fish    .local/share/fish/fish_history
```

(non-exhaustive)

Note that many shells limit the size of the history file. If the user has been executing commands since the date you want to audit, especially for a long time, there's a good chance what you're looking for has been overwritten.

## Security Log

If the command the user ran was done using sudo (That would be a good reason to want to audit it!) then it will appear in the security logs, the most recent one being located at /var/log/auth.log. An entry looks like this:

```
Jun 18 12:00:17 hostname sudo:   username : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/username ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/updatedb
```

However, `logrotate` periodically compresses old logs, so you might have to look at older logs named like `auth.log.4.gz`. An easy way to view these logs without unzipping them is with `zless`:

```
zless /var/log/auth.log.4.gz
```

If you find that they instead opened a shell as root, you could look at *`root`'s* history files. (`root`'s home directory is usually `/root`)

## Bottom line

If the user didn't cover their tracks well, you might be able to find what you're looking for. However, it's not hard to leave no trace, even if the user just got lucky, for example, deleted someone else's archives that they had access to in a shell that didn't record history.